# Selenium Webdriver and Xpath:Complicated selection

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So my structure looks like this at some point. I need to select text ShapeCSR having "select" link using xpath. Both these text present in the same line.

```
<td>
    <img class="imHeader" alt="" src="include/img/context/level_dash.gif"></img><img class="imHeader" alt="" src="include/img/context/icon_telco_level.gif"></img>
    ShapeCSR
</td>
<td> 
    … 
</td>
<td>
    <a id="lnk_LEVEL_2010" href="jfn?isLevel=true&level=L4%3A2010&mfunc=614&cfunc=615&oid=L4%3A2072&ctx=L&jfnRC=5">
          Select
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Well whats unique about it? Is the ID unique, for instance?

Comment: Yes, the ID is unique for all the Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite specific enough but I'm assuming you have a `<table>` of `<tr>` where you want to select the `<td>` containing `"ShapeCSR"` when the `<tr>` contains a `<td>` with the text `"Select"` in it.

Try this:

```
WebElement yourLink = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td/a[contains(text(),'Select')]]/td[contains(text(),'ShapeCSR')]"));
```

Comment: :Where text "Select" is an Link. I need to select <td> containing "ShapeCSR" with <td> containing "Select" link.

Comment: Have you tested my suggestion as I believe it should do as you want.